Spring Security: at which point/filter the URL changes to redirect URL with Oauth2 flow
I have this config:
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig  {


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/api/protected").authenticated();

        http.authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();

        http.oauth2Login((OAuth2LoginConfigurer<HttpSecurity> config) -> {
            config.redirectionEndpoint((OAuth2LoginConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.RedirectionEndpointConfig redirection) -> {
                redirection.baseUri("/testauth");
            });
        });


        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientRegistration clientRegistration() {
        ClientRegistration cr =
                ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("discord")
                        .clientId("1234")
                        .clientSecret("abcd")
                        .scope(new String[]{"email", "identify"})
                        .authorizationUri("https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize")
                        .tokenUri("https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token")
                        .userInfoUri("https://discord.com/api/v10/users/@me")
                        .userNameAttributeName("username")
                        .clientName("Discord")
                        .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                        .redirectUri("http://localhost:8082/testauth")

                        .build();
        return cr;
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        // maps each ClientRepository to its registrationId
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistration());
    }
}

I'm trying to understand when the URl changes from http://localhost:8082/api/protected to /oauth2/authorization/discord. I'm going through debugger's breakpoints and it doesn't look like it's happening inside Oauth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter :
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = this.authorizationRequestResolver.resolve(request);
            if (authorizationRequest != null) {
                this.sendRedirectForAuthorization(request, response, authorizationRequest);
                return;
...

The request inside Oauth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter already has the oauth2/authorization/discord path.
It also doesn't seem to happen inside AuthorizationFilter - it simply rejects the api/protected by throwing an exception:
if (decision != null && !decision.isGranted()) {
                    throw new AccessDeniedException("Access Denied");
                }

Which filter is responsible for changing URL from /api/protected to /oauh2/authorization/discord?

The AccessDeniedException is handle by ExceptionTranslationFilter,then AuthenticationEntryPoint's implement LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint deal.
In spring security 6.3.4 source code Line 123 generate redirect url is /oauh2/authorization/discord
The flow goes like this:
AuthorizationFilter ->
throws AccessDeniedException ->
caught by ExceptionTranslationFilter ->
this.authenticationEntryPoint.commence (which is DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint) ->
delegates to a LinkedHashMap of entrypoints that finds a proper entrypoint based on request's URL ->
entryPoint.commence (which is LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint) ->
has loginFormUrl attribute that is equal to /oauth2/authorization/discord

So the LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint has the proper loginFormUrl set to /oauth2/authorization/discord. But where in Spring code is that setting configured? Or is Spring Boot responsible for it? I tried to search the spring security source code for it, but couldn't find

Line 123 in which .java file were you talking about?

Also, the `Authorization

@parsecer In OAuth2LoginConfigurer code Line 360
